# How to navigate to next view controller in iPhone

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, navigation, uistoryboard, pushviewcontroller

I am newbie to iOS development.I have two view controllers  in my app. I am trying to navigate from first view controller to second view controller in my app.

```
SecondView *ss=[[SecondView alloc] initWithNibName:@"Second Page" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:ss animated:YES];
```

I found this code in "Stack overflow" but it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because you are likely trying to go from one VC to another using Navigator controller code (push) and you likely do not have a navigation controller setup in code or Interface Builder.

You can present/dismiss VCs without using Navigation Controller though and I recommend you start with this.

Notice the terminology: push/pop is used for VCs on the Navigation Controller stack, present/dismiss is for VCs on other VCs (not on a Navigation Controller stack).

There are a couple of way to present a VC on "top" of another VC and it depends on whether that VC exists on your SB as well:

1- If the VC does not exist in your IB and you are just creating and presenting the VC programmatically, you can do:

```
 MyUIViewControllerSubclass *myLittleSubclass=[[MyUIViewControllerSubclass alloc]init];
 myLittleSubclass.view.frame=self.view.frame; //this is for example only
 [self presentViewController:myLittleSubclass animated:YES completion:nil];
```

With the above, you obviously would have to add the MyUIViewControllerSubclass Objective C class first to your project (using add files) and import it to whichever class you are putting the above code.

Later to dismiss it, you can use the following code from the MyUIViewControllerSubclass class itself.

```
 [self.parentViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

2- If you have already added the MyUIViewControllerSubclass Objective C class to your project (using add files) but you intend to use the IB to design it and you have added the VC in the IB and changed its class in the IB to MyUIViewControllerSubclass, you can then use this code:

```
mySubclass *myLittleSubclass=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"theVC"];
[self presentViewController:myLittleSubclass animated:YES completion:nil];
```

You can dismiss same as above. Make sure that you click on the VC in SB and in the identity inspector, put the SB ID as "theVC" and check "Use SB ID".

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have nib name with `Second Page`. Your class name is `SecondView` and nib(xib) name is Second Page then only it will navigate.

Comment: Thanks @Shah Paneri , i forgot about nib name.. now its working